# Jaws not reading role="alert"

Tags: jaws-screen-reader

There is a toaster in my page and I added role="alert" for my toaster container to read out the alert messages being mapped from the back end.

It stopped working after I upgraded my Firefox version to 52.Jaws not reading the role="alert" for latest version of Firefox

Comment: It does look pretty much as a regression, so it should be reported to FF Bugzilla.